# auto-mapping CrudRepository with default rest uri endpoints in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I'm about to create a stock-standard rest CRUD api and have taken note of the handy `CrudRepository` class given in the spring-data framework. I'm planning on also using spring to declare `@RequestMapping`s to hook up the default crud operations to their URL counterparts (e.g. /customer/{id} --> CrudRepository.findOne({id}), etc).

Is there a spring utility class to acheive this or will i need to roll my own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah ha! What I'm looking for is a `org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource` located in the spring data rest webmvc project. maven co-ordinates: "org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc"

an example extract from the [documentation](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/):

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> {

    List<Person> findByLastName(@Param("name") String name);

}
enter code here
```

> This repository is an interface and will allow you to perform various operations involving Person objects. It gets these operations by >  extending the PagingAndSortingRepositry interface defined in Spring Data Commons.
>
> At runtime, Spring Data REST will create an implementation of this interface automatically. Then it will use the @RepositoryRestResource >  annotation to direct Spring MVC to create RESTful endpoints at /people.